# write Parquet file with Scalavro and Parquet-avro

Tags: scala, avro, parquet

I need write a file in parquet fileformat, for read after with spark.
I use scala with Scalavro and Parquet-avro.

In my test I have write a file in avro format and work fine:

```
import java.io._
import com.gensler.scalavro.types.AvroType
import scala.util.{ Success, Failure }

//object structure
case class defMyList(mydata:String)
case class objectTest(name: String, desc:String,myList:Seq[defMyList])

def test()
{

    //create object data 
    val objectList = objectTest(
      name = "object name",
      desc = "object desc",
      myList = Seq(
        defMyList("asdfasdfasfsafsdfasdfasdf"),
        defMyList("asdfasdfasfsafsdfasdfasdf")
      )
    )


    val objectListType = AvroType[objectTest]

    println("schema: " + objectListType.schema)

    val filestream= new File("C:\\avrofile.avro")
    val outStream = new FileOutputStream(filestream)
    objectListType.io.write(objectList, outStream)

    val inStream: java.io.InputStream = new FileInputStream(filestream)

    objectListType.io.read(inStream) match {
      case Success(readResult) => println("Successfully deserialized: " + readResult)
      case Failure(cause)      => println("Failure")
    }

}
```

How can I change this code for write in parquet format?

thank you